# Man training his aging father to pass a mandatory test to remain alive

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I'm trying to find out the name of a story I read decades ago, about a man training his aging father who needs to pass a mandatory test that will allow him to remain alive. The man worries about his father's failing memory, who keeps on trying to no avail. Then the morning of the test, the man wakes up only to find a farewell note from his father.

It was a short story, just a few pages long. It painted a very dystopian future as the old man needed to pass the test to avoid being destroyed. It could have been Bradbury -both in character and length- but can't seem to find the story among his books.

Any ideas on this particular story?

Comment: Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy! Please try to add anything that may help identification. Review this [**checklist**](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question/9337#9337).  What language was it in? Are there any **other** plot details you remember or descriptions of scenes or characters you can give? Anything at all? Feel free to [edit] any additional details into the question. You might also want to provide a more descriptive question title next time.

Comment: Was this a novel, short story..in an anthology?

Comment: Hi Paulie. It was a short story, just a few pages long. It painted a very dystopian future as the old man needed to pass the test to avoid being destroyed. It could have been Bradbury -both in character and length- but can't seem to find the story among his books.

Comment: "The Test" by Richard Matheson.

Comment: That's it! Thank you so much, so nice to be surrounded by such knowledgeable people. I read it in spanish about 35 years ago. I don't recall it being 20 pages long, so it must have been an abridged version. Still an amazing and touching story. Thank you everyone!

Comment: @chris You're welcome! You can [accept](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) the answer below by clicking on the check mark next to it.

Answer (score 12):

**I'm trying to find out the name of a story**

I believe you're thinking of [Richard Matheson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Richard_Matheson)'s short story ["The Test"](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?40882) though a couple of points don't exactly match your description: the story is 20 pages long in the copy I'm looking at, and the old man doesn't leave a note.

**I read decades ago,**

"The Test" was first published in [*The Magazine of Fantasy and Science Fiction*, November 1954](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?61331) (available at the [Internet Archive](https://archive.org/stream/Fantasy_Science_Fiction_v007n05_1954-11_Gorgon776/Fantasy__Science_Fiction_v007n05_1954-11_Gorgon776#page/n55/mode/2up)), and has been reprinted many times; any of [these covers](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/titlecovers.cgi?40882) look familiar?

**about a man training his aging father who needs to pass a mandatory test**

> The night before the test, Les helped his father study in the dining room. Jim and Tommy were asleep upstairs and, in the living room, Terry was sewing, her face expressionless as the needle moved with a swift rhythmic piercing and drawing.
>
> Tom Parker sat very straight, his lean, vein-ribbed hands clasped together on the table top, his pale blue eyes looking intently at his son's lips as though it might help him to understand better.
>
> He was eighty and this was his fourth test.
>
> "All right," Les said, reading from the sample test Doctor Trask had gotten them. "Repeat the following sequences of numbers."

**that will allow him to remain alive.**

> That was the horror.
>
> Life went on as usual. No one spoke of dying. The government sent out letters and the tests were given and those who failed were requested to appear at the government center for their injections. The law operated, the death rate was steady, the population problem was contained—all officially, impersonally, without a cry or a sensation.
>
> But it was still loved people who were being killed.

**The man worries about his father's failing memory, who keeps on trying to no avail.**

> Les licked his lips nervously, then hid the trembling of them behind his cup. Talking, he thought, talking and talking—of cars and tube conveyors and examination schedules—when all the time both of them knew that Tom might be sentenced to death that day.

**Then the morning of the test, the man wakes up only to find a farewell note from his father.**

Not exactly:

> For a long time they looked at each other without speaking, like total strangers, each waiting for the other one to speak. How did the test go? Les heard the words repeated in his mind. How did the test go, how did the test go? He couldn't speak the words. How did the—
>
> "I suppose you want to know what . . . happened," his father said then, controlling himself visibly.
>
> "Yes," Les said. "I . . ." He caught himself. "Yes," he repeated and waited.
>
> Old Tom looked down at the floor for a moment. Then, suddenly, he raised his head and looked defiantly at his son.
>
> "*I didn't go,*" he said.
>
> [. . . .]
>
> "He's been to the drugstore," Les said. "I . . . saw the bag in the corner of the room. He threw it away so I wouldn't see it but I . . . saw it.
>
> They stood silently in the dining room while rain drummed against the windows.
>
> "He must have shown the druggist the letter about the test," Les said. "The . . . druggist must have given him . . . pills. Like they all do."

Comment: Are the pills a method of suicide? If so, why are they preferable to government execution?

Comment: They are suicide pills. In real life, for whatever reason, people have been known to commit suicide to "cheat the hangman" or attempt to do so. In the story, the official procedure involves waiting several weeks after the test for an appointment, and then going to a government facility. I guess the old man wanted to skip the waiting period and die at home.

Comment: @Adamant the advantage is to save the family the horror of living with a "walking dead" for *weeks*. This is clearly painted by Matheson - *The Test* is actually one of the most disturbing stories I recall having read. The final of the story manages to be creepy even after we're told of the pills and we realize what the old man must have done.